# SCIM and web api 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, scim, scim2

I am trying to implement SCIM with Web Api 2 (c#) and I've found the [nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SystemForCrossDomainIdentityManagement/) and [some documentation from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/use-scim-to-provision-users-and-groups) and their [sample code](https://github.com/Azure/AzureAD-BYOA-Provisioning-Samples/tree/master).

My understanding from the [SCIM documentation](http://www.simplecloud.info/) is that they just need an API with the specified user/Group methods and schemas, but in the sample code they have used a monitor and provider.

```
    public Startup()
    {
        IMonitor monitor = new DefaultMonitor();
        IProvider provider = new SampleProvider();
        this.starter = new WebApplicationStarter(provider, monitor);
    }
```

Their code doesn't compile even after following the instructions and getting nuget packages most probably because of the old resources on the packages that they have used, but also I don't see what is the nececity of using the package other than adding some interfaces for my controllers.

I've also found this: 
[SCIM (System for Cross-domain Identity Management) library for C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16390464/scim-system-for-cross-domain-identity-management-library-for-c-sharp)
But it is also a shame that the blog post that they are pointing to from MS is gone :.

So what I am asking is:
- Am I going the correct direction? Should I use the nuget?
And if yes, anything special on Web api?

- Any suggestion is also very appreciated.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? :D